# Prevent file browsing

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, security

I have two questions as below:

First,I provided the file download functionality to the user, but when user copies the URL and paste in another browser, I do not want the download to get started start, instead I want this to be started only when user navigates from link in the application.

Second how to prevent file browsing in asp.net? I tried

```
<directoryBrowse enabled="false"/>
```

in web.config. but was not useful.

Comment: Please don't seed your question title with tags - it's not necessary.

Comment: You can't do this with a simple setting.  Your web server never truly knows where a URL is being requested from.  That's the nature of the Internet.  What type of security are you trying to achieve?  If you only want authenticated users to access certain files then you can serve the file as a MVC or Web Api action method and check that the user is logged in or has certain permissions/roles/etc before serving the file.

Comment: @TrevorElliott you could do a referrer check, that would raise the bar enough to weed out maybe 1/4 of the people not following the link. But yea, if you want better than 1/4 it's going to be a lot more work (cookies, one time use urls, ect.)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Never thought of that.  Though now that I think of it you might end up with some angry users whose browser/plugin/internet security suite is removing the referrer.

Comment: I just read an article on CodeProject showing how to use javascript to set window.name to a GUID. This in combination with a file handler could in fact prevent direct link downloads.

Answer (score 0):

got the solution,

Option 1.you can add the web.config file to the directory in which the file you want to restrict the access exist and add following lines to the web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
   <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
   </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

OR

Option 2. You can add following lines to the existing root web.config.

```
<configuration>
<location path="DirectoryName">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/> <!-- Denies Anonymous Users -->
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
</configuration>
```