# Is there any security threats, of being able to access the Content folder items using web browsers, for unauthorized users

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an asp.net mvc web application, and inside my Content folder I have items such as the site.css, the logo , ajax.png.

I thought that the asp.net mvc will prevent the users from accessing the Content folder item directly, and these items can only be viewed when called from an action method, or atleast from an authenticated users . Currently if a user (how did not login to the system) types the following

```
https://..../OurProject /Content/ajax.png
```

he will be able to see the image directly .i am not sure if this is a security problem, or it is normal to have such ability?. Baring in mind that I have used the `[Authorized]` annotation inside all the controller classes, but seems that the content folder items can be viewed by unauthenticated users?
can anyone advice ?
Thanks

Comment: It would be *unusual* to have something in the `Content` folder that is of a sensitive nature, such that its worth trying to prevent someone casually accessing it.

Comment: i do not have anything sensitive inside the Content folder,, but the idea that unauthenticated user can access any of the site content (images, logos ,etc) even if it is not sensitive (as in my case) should be avoided i think??

Comment: Well, I can assure you that this is the default behaviour. There may be ways to prevent it, but if you've got a choice between spending a day on this (that your users will never know nor care about) or spending a day working on new features, I know which I'd recommend.

Comment: This is really strange behaviour. Are you 100% sure the specific users accessing the Content folder are unauthorized? I would suggest that the annotation is to enforce authorization for that Action.

Comment: the annotation are on the controller class,, i am talking about the Content folder...

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19463171/413180) - the title is slightly incorrect, but you can implement the `web.config` settings to prevent anon access to `Content`.